# Print values from several array using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of numbers. For example:

```
a = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Now I need to create another two array from `a` based on some criteria. Say `x` array of even number numbers and `y` array of odd numbers.

I have done that. But the next thing is, I want to publish them as below:

```
z   x   y
1       1
2   2  
3       3
4   4
5       5
6   6
```

I dont know how to print the void places as I have already created x and y array from z. Any help?

Comment: So If I am getting this correctly, x and y are sublists of z , and they are also mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to print a large space is to insert a tab. This is simply done by printing `"\t"` which represents a tab character.

This code does it:

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print "z\tx\ty"  # Print top line separated by tab characters
for i in a:  # For each element in the list
    if i % 2 == 0:  # If the element is even
        print i, "\t", i
    else:  # If it is odd
        print i, "\t\t", i
```

Output:

```
z   x   y
1       1
2   2
3       3
4   4
5       5
6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [simple indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing)  :

```
>>> a =np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> x,y=a[0::2],a[1::2]
>>> x
array([1, 3, 5])
>>> y
array([2, 4, 6])
```

Or as a more general way to applying a condition on your array you can use `np.where` :

```
>>> np.where(a%2!=0)[0]
array([0, 2, 4])
>>> 
>>> np.where(a%2==0)[0]
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
a = (3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print "z\tx\ty"
for i,e in enumerate(a):  
    print i, "\t"*(i%2+1), e
```

This is a shorter version of solution proposed by Red Shift.